# Image loading issue from HTML in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm working on project where requirement is to show html file inside the UITextView. there are some image in HTML file as well. HTML is loading correctly in UITextView but image is broken while loading. instead of actual image,  folder/file icon is visible inside UITextView. here is HTML I am loading in UITextView -

```
let htmlString = "<html><body><h1>This is the title</h1><p>This is the first paragraph.</p><img src=\"https://miro.medium.com/max/9216/1*QzxcfBpKn5oNM09-vxG_Tw.jpeg\" width=\"360\" height=\"240\"><p>This is the second paragraph.</p><p>This is the third paragraph.</p><p>This is the fourth paragraph.</p><p>This is the last paragraph.</p></body></html>"
```

**here is code to convert the HTMl string to NSAttributedString**-

```
extension String {
    func convertToAttributedFromHTML() -> NSAttributedString? {
        var attributedText: NSAttributedString?
        let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue]
        if let data = data(using: .unicode, allowLossyConversion: true), let attrStr = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: options, documentAttributes: nil) {
            attributedText = attrStr
        }
        return attributedText
    }
}
```

here I am setting the attribute String to textView-

```
label.attributedText = htmlString.convertToAttributedFromHTML()
```

Finally while rendering the above attribute String on UITextView ,broken image is visible in attached screenshot-
[image: you can see folder icon is visible instead of actual image]

**Please let me know what I am missing here so image can be displayed properly**

Comment: Hi there. I'm having the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?